# Making a Bejeweled Blitz clone

Tags: c#, clone

so I've got to make a Bejeweled Blitz clone for my Programming I. class in **C#**, but I'm a bit stuck on it, because it's a little above my current knowledge, so I would like to some help from you guys.

The task is as follows:

> Make a Bejeweled Blitz clone. In this game, the field is 79*24 maximum,
>   and there are balls scattered on the field with different colors. The
>   object of the game, is to erase as many balls as possible by switching
>   two adjacent balls, so that there will be two or more balls of the
>   same color next to each other. These balls are erased from the game,
>   and the balls above them take their respective place and the emptiness
>   on the top of the field will be filled with new balls with random
>   colors. Erased balls are worth point depending on the number of erased
>   balls. So 2 erased balls are worth 2 point up to 5 points. At the
>   beginning of the game the player states their name and for how long
>   they want to play in minutes. At the end of the game the player's
>   name, the duration of the game and the score goes into the
>   leaderboards, which is arranged in duration then score. The
>   leaderboards are stored in a txt file.

So this would be the program I have to write in **C#**. I'm not really sure as to how to do this, so I would really appreciate some help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am not sure what you expect from us other then doing the task for you? I am sure your school must have given you something else? At least a library or engine to make it in?

Comment: I think you should store the leaderboards in a text file.

Comment: Think about the classes you'll need, their behavior, and the design of the program.  If you haven't learned that in your class so far there's not much that can be done here.

Comment: Write a bunch a classes that represent the nouns in the question. Write methods that represent the verbs. Use read from the console for input and write to the console for output. When you have a text version working, progress to adding more features. Come back to SO when you have a programming question.

Comment: Too broad you say? I said in the first paragraph that it's above me, so yeah I was expecting a solution with instructions to help me understand how it's done but okay then.

Answer (score 1):

I understand your problem, because when I was in school I had same problem with my game development project. My Answer is going to be a starting point, so it may qualify for some hater from you.

First you need to be clear on

1. Entity object of your game. For example how a GEM will be stored in memory, or behave like on mouse over etc. You need to write them down and define various classes based on them. [pseudo classes only]
2. Then you need to search a Game Engine if you want, I would rather go with default WPF or Windows Form for fact they were in my skill set when I start learning C# at my time [Oh I built a Chess Game].
3. Learn how you handle mouse click on GRID of Screen that is not consist of Button or Textfield, but a Picture box probably. and with mouse position you find the underlying gem etc.
4. Then attach them :).

Yes it is simplest and yet the toughest start. But all will be clear if you get #1 done. I put my chess game source at http://vschessmania.codeplex.com/ It use above start only, different game, but has all what you need to built with a Game Engine.